# Pointing an array of string inside a void

Tags: c++, c, struct, void-pointers, double-pointer

I have a little problem passing a pointer inside a void. This void show only the firts position of the array of struct. When the loop go to second position i get "segmentation fault".I tried to show the array inside the main with the same loop and it works.What's the problem?

```
typedef struct starr{
    char string[100];
    int occ;
} starr;

int main(){
    int n;
    starr *array_str;
    //insert n and array_str
    array_str=(starr *)malloc(sizeof(starr)*n);
    view(&array_str,n);
}

void view(starr *array_str, n){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("String %s",array_str[i]->string);
    }
}
```

Comment: ``view(array_str, n);`` Because it's already a ``starr *``

Comment: Though I should also point out that unless you use ``calloc`` instead of ``malloc`` you'll be printing garbage bytes.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `C++`?

Comment: If this is really `C`, **you need to post the header files you included**.   The code you posted will behave differently if the header file for `malloc` is not included.

Comment: If this is C++, use `std::string` and container classes (and you don't need the `typedef`), otherwise don't tag C++ (C != C++).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct starr {
    char string[100];
    int occ;
} starr;

void view(starr *array_str, size_t n);

int main() {
    size_t n;
    // initialize n
    starr *array_str;
    array_str = (starr *)calloc(n, sizeof(starr));
    // do stuff with array_str
    view(array_str, n);

    free(array_str); // go! be free!
}

void view(starr *array_str, size_t n) {
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("String %s", array_str[i].string);
    }
}
```

1: `view` accepts a `starr *`, and `array_str` is already that type so there is no need to reference it with `&`.

2: since `array_str` is a `starr *`, an index of it (e.g. `array_str[i]`) is a `starr` so use the `.` notation instead of the `->` notation.

3: `calloc` will clear the bytes when declaring memory so that they will be initialized to `NULL` bytes and you'll avoid printing a string that may cause buffer overflow, if you don't give them proper values first for whatever reason.

4: `n` should be type `size_t` to be consistent with its meaning, which is the number of indices in an array.

5: don't forget to `free(array_str);` since you initialized it using `malloc` / `calloc`.

Comment: Thanks for support. I fixed it deleting the '&'. Of course its only a part of the code. It's just an example of the problem because i have no internet now to post all the complete code. I wrote alla of that with my phone. Thank you again